is there a way to get gcp vm list faster
when I use gcp api libraries I have to send request for all available zones for a specific project to find the vm s on my project.
Tried concurrent feature library in python.But want a different faster method.

I think that's the only way you can get that data. If you're already doing it concurrent or in parallel for each possible zone that would be the solution. You can't get that data with something similar as "Get all instances in X project".
